# Use getPerspectiveTransform to obtain transformation matrix and then use it to transform a single point into warped space

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, linear-algebra, matrix-transform

I have the following image:

[image]

As you can see, there is a green point there with coordinates (x1,y1). Next, I identify some reference and target points in order to get the corresponding perspective transformation matrix using:

```
matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(referencePoints, targetPoints)
```

How should I use that matrix to transform just the (x1,y1) point into a new point (x2,y2) with the new perspective.

[image]

As an additional example, imagine you have two points in the original image with a distance d1 between them, but you want the true distance d2 between those two points. Then, you should transform both points into the new space (with a birds eye perspective) and calculate the distance again.

In particular, the transformation matrix is:

```
matrix = array([[ 3.51546299e+00,  1.70317103e+01,  3.42045887e+02],
                [-9.18633633e-01,  1.31323789e+01,  1.77154086e+03],
                [ 2.00130923e-06,  2.07269593e-03,  1.00000000e+00]])
```

And the point I want to transform is:

```
A = [303.7355, 1101.029]
```

Thank you

Comment: you can eithrr use the function perspectiveTransform (but your single point in sn empty list) or extend your point to homogeneois coordinates, multiply by thr perspective transformation and divide by the z coordinate.

Comment: Did you meant the following? For example, if my point is 

A = [303.7355, 1101.029].  

And my matrix is: 

matrix = array([[ 3.51546299e+00,  1.70317103e+01,  3.42045887e+02],
                        [-9.18633633e-01,  1.31323789e+01,  1.77154086e+03],
                        [ 2.00130923e-06,  2.07269593e-03,  1.00000000e+00]]).  

So I need to do this: 

result = cv2.perspectiveTransform(A, matrix)  

But it gave me an error. (The example I just used is the real one)

Comment: Oh, I think I just solved it with base math (homogeneous coordinates). Thank you anyway. For anyone with the same problem, just add an extra z coordinate with a 1 to the point you want to transform and multiply it with the matrix. Then divide the resulting vector by it's z coordinate and just take the first two coordinates to form a bidimensional point. That's your point.

Comment: yes! And sorry for all the typos in my first comment. Hope this didn't make it hard to find the necessary math parts :D